# AWS CloudWatch Zero Queue Size For One Week alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am wondering if there is a way to set up a CloudWatch alarm that will alarm if an SQS queue has not received any traffic for 7 days. I currently have a job that runs on my host once a week that is guaranteed to add message to my SQS queue, I already have a way of alarming if the job doesn't run but I would also like to alarm if for some reason the job does run but does not send any messages to my queue. I understand that the longest alarm period you can set is 1 day. Is there another way to create an alarm that will do what I am looking for?

Edit:
Since my job runs once a week is there a way to have an alarm that will monitor metrics every 7th day, seeing if any traffic hits the queue within a 24 hour time frame? This is more accurate seeing as the 6 days in between I don't expect or care if there is any traffic only that there is traffic on that 7th day.

Comment: If your queue is completely inactive for more than a few hours, SQS puts it into sort of a sleep mode and stops sending stats to CloudWatch.  So you may actually have 2 problems to solve.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - With CloudWatch Alarms you can now select how to treat missing data. You can treat it as bad (breaching the threshold), good (not breaching) or just ignore it: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/03/cloudwatch-alarms-releases-two-new-alarm-configuration-settings/

Comment: @Tartaglia brilliant.  Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 4):

CloudWatch Alarms set a limit that `period * number_of_datapoints_to_watch` must be less than 24 hours. As far as I know, there is no way around that.

To get the behavior you want, you can calculate *days since last activity* yourself, publish that as a custom metric and alarm on that.

One way to do it would be:

1. Create a lambda function and have it trigger every hour for example.
2. In the lambda, call CloudWatch GetMetricStatistics for the SQS metric you want to monitor.
3. Get the latest datapoint returned that has value greater than 0 and calculate the difference between now and the timestamp on that datapoint.
4. Use CloudWatch PutMetricData to publish this value to your new metric `days-since-last-activity`.
5. Now you can alarm when the value of your new metric goes above 7 days.